# Save reverse Foreign Key in Django CreateView

Tags: django, django-views

I have these 2 models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Contact person"))
    ...
```

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', null=True, blank=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Company"))
    ...
```

I want to automatically fill the `company` field when using Django's `CreateView` based on the current logged-in user. Because every `Company` model has a `ForeignKey` relationship with `User`. So I override the form_valid method, but how can I get the correct value here for the company field?

```
class AssignmentCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.company = self.request.user
        super(AssignmentCreateView, self).save(form)
```

Comment: But if a `Company` has a `ForeignKey` to the user, then a user has *zero*, one, or *more* related `Company`s. Hence you can not set the "company of the user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    company = Company.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    form.instance.company = company
    valid_data = super(AssignmentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    return valid_data
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is what I was looking for. But `Company.objects.get(user=self.request.user)` should be `Company.objects.get(contact_person=self.request.user)` because of the field name in my model.